# installing composer on a shared host

Tags: php, cgi, composer-php

I am trying to install composer on my shared host for the first time.

When I run `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` 
I am getting a Composer successfully installed
User it: `php composer.phar`

when I run `php composer.phar` i am getting this warring error:

**Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI**

any ideas on how to fix this ? and why i am getting this error ? :(

when I run `php -v` i get this back

```
PHP 5.4.39 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Mar 25 2015 14:20:20)  
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group  
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies  
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

*Do I need to run this using CLI version if so how would i do this ?*

Any help would be nice thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this yet? https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1513#issuecomment-45207197

Comment: I have tryed $ php -d register_argc_argv=1 "./composer.phar" install from the link and i am getting the same error Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI ....it also says use php-cli vendor/bin/phpunit to run PHPUnit. how would i do that?...thank you for your help

Comment: Is PHPUnit installed? https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

Comment: Thank you ....i will try it out and let you know ....sorry im a newbie :)

Comment: Please try  `php-cli -v` and then `php-cli composer.phar`

Comment: I will try it out and let you know...thank you

Comment: Thank you everyone....jens A it seemed to work :)

Comment: @JensA.Koch you should put your comment as an answer as you should get credits :)

Answer (score 10):

I resolved this by explicitly calling the version of PHP it asked for. Keep in mind that on a shared server environment there is often multiple versions of PHP running and even though you may have set up your default in your cPanel config, bash commands often resolve to another (lower) version.

First, I created a `bin` directory and moved composer.phar into it. Then, I added this alias to my .bash_profile and it worked like a charm:

```
alias composer="/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php-cli ~/bin/composer.phar"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

As Composer is now available via WHM you can use this to find it:

```
which composer
```

This returned path "/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer" for me. If this returns nothing then disregard the rest of this answer, as Composer is not available to you at system level.

You can now use `php-cli` to call this with Composer's absolute path:

```
php-cli /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer install
php-cli /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update
php-cli /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer require whatever/example
```

You may however need to alias `php-cli` if your system claims this isn't found. It very much depends how PHP has been deployed on the WHM server. You can do this by adding a user alias to the end of your ".bashrc" file as follows:

```
alias php-cli=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php
```

*Replace `ea-php72` with the release of PHP you want to use. Submit this as a command in the shell to make it available immediately, otherwise it'll become available when you open your next Bash session.*

If you want to make this available with just `composer` alone you could create this alias again in ".bashrc":

```
alias composer=/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer
```

Or

```
php-cli $(which composer) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of the php versions installed will vary from host to host. Try finding them with:

```
locate /bin/php
```

For me this lists all php versions and I can then replace php with, for example:

```
/usr/bin/php71-cli
```

To access the command line interface version rather than the default cgi one. Then as stated by @Diggery you can create an alias.

```
alias composer='/usr/bin/php71-cli bin/composer.phar'
```

There are many suggestions on StackOverflow on how to test for a cli installation but the above is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a script to handle changes in composer/vendor. The script works with ftp-only servers, sends/removes only the changed files. Maybe someone will find it useful.

https://github.com/psad73/tune-composer