# Composer Install command throwing error in Centos VPS server

Tags: linux, yii, centos, composer-php

I am trying to run composer install command in my project root directory. As you can see in composer.json file is present in the file listing.[image]

But when I try to execute the composer install command i get an error saying that Composer could not find a composer.json file in /opt/cpanel/composer/bin directory. Why am i getting this error ?

This is a centos vps server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900211/composer-could-not-find-a-composer-json

Comment: i have seen this thread. but did not help me.

Comment: Your problem is: **Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI**
see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814578](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814578/)